# What does `if file.find('freq-') != -1` mean?

Tags: python, string, glob

I'm a chemistry student and want to write a script to extract some data (like coupling constants and interproton distance) from gaussian output files.

I found a script which extracts chemical shifts from gaussian output files. However, I don't understand what does `if file.find('freq-') !=-1` mean in the script.

Here's part of the script (since the script also does other things as well so I've just sown the bit relevant to my question):

```
def read_gaussian_freq_outfiles(list_of_files):
    list_of_freq_outfiles = []
    for file in list_of_files:
        if file.find('freq-') !=-1:
            list_of_freq_outfiles.append([file,int(get_conf_number(file)),open(file,"r").readlines()])

    return list_of_freq_outfiles

def read_gaussian_outputfiles():
    list_of_files = []
    for file in glob.glob('*.out'):
        list_of_files.append(file)
    return list_of_files
```

I think in the `def read_gaussian_outputfiles()` bit, we create a list of file and simply add all file with extension '.out' to the list.

The `read_gaussian_freq_outfiles(list_of_files)` bit has probably list files which has "freq-" in the file name. But what does the `file.find('freq-')!=-1` mean?

Does it mean if whatever we find in the file name doesn't equal to -1, or something else?

Some other additional information: the format of the gaussian output filename is: `xxxx-opt_freq-conf-yyyy.out` where `xxxx` is the name of your molecule and `yyyy` is a number.

Comment: Did you try the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find)?

Comment: Yes I did read this page, but when I read it I didn't fully understand what's going on. I'm new to Python (and the reason why I start learning is to write a script to extract whatever I want to extract as I mentioned in the post)...... So I'm still struggling to understand explanation provided in the doc you attached. Reading the doc again with the example you provided make things A LOT clearer! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `s.find(foo)` fails to find `foo` in `s`, it returns `-1`. Therefore, when `s.find(foo)` does not return `-1`, we know it didn't fail.

`read_gaussian_freq_outfiles` looks for the term `"freq-"` in each of the names of files in `list_of_files`. If it succeeds in finding this phrase in the name of a file, it appends a list containing this file, a "conf number" (not sure what this is), and the contents of the file, to a list called `list_of_freq_outfiles`.

I created three files, `goodbye.txt`, `hello.txt`, and `helloworld.txt` to demonstrate usage.

In this example, I'll print all files that end with `.txt`, create a list of files, then print all files that have the phrase `"goodbye"` in the filename. This should only print `goodbye.txt`.

```
09:53 $ ls
goodbye.txt    hello.txt      helloworld.txt
(venv) ✔ ~/Desktop/ex 
09:53 $ python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Dec  5 2015, 14:44:47) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import glob
>>> for file in glob.glob('*.txt'):
...   print(file)
... 
goodbye.txt
hello.txt
helloworld.txt
>>> list_of_files = [ file for file in glob.glob('*.txt') ]
>>> print(list_of_files)
['goodbye.txt', 'hello.txt', 'helloworld.txt']
>>> for file in list_of_files:
...   if file.find('goodbye') != -1:
...     print(file)
... 
goodbye.txt
```

Indeed, `goodbye.txt` is the only file printed.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers also show: if .find() retrieves -1, it cannot find what you're looking for. This has to do with the fact that .find will return the first index at which it can find your query. So in the following sentence

```
The cat is on the mat
```

and sentence.find('cat'), it will return 4 (since 'cat' starts at index 4 (it starts at 0!)).

However, sentence.find('dog') will return the only thing it can return if it cannot find it: -1. If it returned 0 as the 'cannot find', you might think your query starts at index 0. With -1, you know it could not find it.

Comment: Aha! That's why it returns -1 not 0 ^^

Comment: Nice Explanation

Answer (score 1):

String find method in python looks at the occurrence of a sub-string in a given string (ref http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm)

Here it is looking for all the filenames with 'freq-' sub-string in them.

Comment: `Here it is looking for all files with 'freq-' substring in them.` Technically it's looking for files with 'freq-' in *their name*.

Comment: that's what I meant, made the changes. Thanks you

Comment: After reading Nander Speerstra's comments, I fully understand the output result of the example you posted. In first two cases it returns 15 because you can find the string 'exam' starting from index 15. And at the 3rd case you can't find it because you start the search from index 40 (I think?).